# problemas con acceder a propiedades de un objecto en un request graphQl

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, graphql

Hola estoy trabajando en un proyecto react con apollographQL y estoy teniendo problemas para acceder a las propiedades del objeto que me llega desde el servidor graphQl con base de datos mongodb. Declare un objeto de prueba en el mismo componente y si puedo acceder a sus propiedades, realmente no se que mas hacer. Les pongo el código y los logs de la consola.

La pregunta es: Por que no puedo acceder a las propiedades del objeto que viene en a data?

--- Componente Profile

```
import React from 'react';

import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

const GET_CURRENT_USER = gql`
{
product (_id: "5b6ba3c9c7d76b0f5c7a2c36"){
  _id
  name
  description  
 }
 }
`;
//Object for test
const test = {
name: "jhon",
second: "levi"
};

 const Profile = () =>
 <Query query={GET_CURRENT_USER}>
{({ data }) => {
    const { product } = data;
    console.log(product)
    console.log(test)
  return (
    <div>
      {product.name}
      {test.name}
    </div>
  );
}}
```

export default Profile;

Salida de la consola [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola ya resolví el problema. Después de analizar por varias horas los logs me di cuenta que la primera vez que carga la pagina el data que viene como respuesta del query de graphql viene undefined , y el segundo si viene con datos. Entonces en un post encuentro que hay que poner las condicionales para el error y el loading para evitar hacer el render si el servidor demora en responder o hubo algún problema de comunicación. Puesta estas instrucciones resuelto el problema

---Asi quedo el codigo

```
import React from 'react';

 import gql from 'graphql-tag';
 import { Query } from 'react-apollo';

 const GET_CURRENT_USER = gql`
 {
 product (_id: "5b6ba3c9c7d76b0f5c7a2c36"){
  _id
  name
  description 
  price 
 }
 }
 `;

 const Profile = () =>
 <Query query={GET_CURRENT_USER}>
 {({ loading, error, data }) => {
    const { product } = data;
    console.log(product)
   if (loading) return "Loading...";
   if (error) return `Error! ${error.message}`;
  return (
    <div>
      <p>El producto {product.name} es exquisito para un 
 {product.description} y tiene un valor de $ {product.price}</p>
    </div>
  );
 }}
</Query>
export default Profile;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]